# How can I pass a VSTS variable into a property file in a MVN project

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops

I have to pass database, username and password to connect to a database from VSTS. I am executing a maven project.

I defined the variables in VSTS.
I want to have a property file like

```
datasource.url="${database}"
datasource.username="${username}"
datasource.password="${password}"
```

Is possible to do this? or should I get the variables from the java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is possible to do this? or should I get the variables from the java
>   code?

Of course it can. And you don't need to do other complex operation, just use an task which name is [Replace Tokens task](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme).

It's not only work in the `.config` file, but also very effective in the .properties file.

As your sample, just change the definition of the variable so that it can be access correctly:

```
datasource.url="#{database}#"
datasource.username="#{username}#"
datasource.password="#{password}#"
```

The format of variable in `.properties` file is `#{VariableName}#`.

And then, add the task Replace Tokens task into your pipeline. Add the value on the **Variable** tab:

[image]

For task configuration, just need to specify the value of **Target files**:

[image]

After build filnished, locate to the local file. Here is my test result, you can see that the replace is successful:

[image]

Note: While you build with this task, it will report some error message like: `##[error]EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read`. But actually it does not affect these variable replace operation. You will see that the file has been replace successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Create a task for it. For example in build pipeline:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: 'sed -i "s/\${database}/\$(database)/g" db.properties'
    displayName: 'inject properties'
```

And so on.